# Does Google Sheets have an equivalent functions to WEBSERVICE and FILTERXML in Excel?

Tags: excel, web-services, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Context: I am trying to calculate the distance between two places using either Bing Maps or Google Maps.

There is a spreadsheet here which demonstrates what I'm trying to do:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TsmIPDUrCOkScNqPmiVrYVXb1SRzP9Vl/view?usp=sharing

I want to return a response in a single cell from a function (that works in the same way as WEBSERVICE in Excel, but in Google Sheets instead) that calls a dev.virtualearth.net URL with a query, such as the following URL:

https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?countryRegion=New Zealand&adminDistrict=Wellington&locality=Johnsonville&postalCode=6037&addressLine=Bassett Rd&maxResults=1&o=xml&key=ArTkC_A3xj__NuzbJVV2Lq9oo8sftT1r9peJOlYpWVdvTJWDzn1HBq22A48Pn9W-0

I can see that there are functions such as IMPORTDATA, IMPORTXML, but these don't work in exactly the same way as the WEBSERVICE function in Excel.

I also need an equivalent function to FILTERXML.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot open your sample of `There is a spreadsheet here which demonstrates what I'm trying to do:`. I apologize for this. Can you confirm it again?

Comment: My bad, I have just edited the permissions so that anyone can view and comment! Please try again!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TsmIPDUrCOkScNqPmiVrYVXb1SRzP9Vl/edit#gid=35723592

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could confirm it. I have a question. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? For example, in order to correctly understand abuot your goal, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? In your question, the URL of `https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?countryRegion=New Zealand&adminDistrict=Wellington&locality=Johnsonville&postalCode=6037&addressLine=Bassett Rd&maxResults=1&o=xml&key=###` is the sample input value you expect? If it's so, can you provide the sample output value you expect?

Comment: I am not entirely sure yet what the sample output would be, but it just needs to work in the same way as the WEBSERVICE function in Excel as this is what I was given originally. I am just exploring using IMPORTXML, instead of a combination of WEBSERVICE and FILTERXML, which would be used in Excel.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Although I cannot still understand about your goal from your replying, I would like to try to understand it. For example, when you want to use `https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?countryRegion=New Zealand&adminDistrict=Wellington&locality=Johnsonville&postalCode=6037&addressLine=Bassett Rd&maxResults=1&o=xml&key=###`, can you provide the sample output from this URL and the values you want to retrieve?

Comment: That's OK. As can be seen from the spreadsheet, I need to get response XML from the request to the URL, then filter it to get a statuscode, latitude and longitude. And then use a distance Lookup Bing Maps app URL query, passing as arguments two locations, travel mode and a Bing Maps key.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about the sample input and output you expect. But, when I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, in the xml file, there is a link for a 'namespace' : xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1". You then will have to fetch data within [local-name() ='xxxxx']. As an example, put in C24

```
=transpose(IMPORTXML(C19,"//*[local-name() ='Point']"))
```

and you will get both Lat and Lon at the same time
You can also retrieve all informations by

```
=IMPORTXML(C19,"//*")
```

See cells with yellow background https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N4G_0WUQfBStCzbG3lkcAPhVAhL5EcYJbOTTIXwMswc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The example Google Sheets uses `FILTERXML`. Should it not use the `IMPORTXML`?

Comment: I could be wrong, but Google Sheets doesn't have a function called FILTERXML (which is an Excel function)